# Is `h` a valid heading tag in PDFs?

Tags: accessibility, pdf

I'm configuring a document in InDesign for basic accessibility. The documents I'm working on have unfortunately used h1-h6 tags incorrectly for page hierarchy (basically heading style option 1, style option 2, etc), and the quick fix I'm looking at until we can address the overall fix of the style template is to categorize all headings as a single level (so that it at least knows what is a header and what isn't).

When configuring the document in InDesign, there are two different "export tag" settings. One for HTML/EPUB, and another for PDF. In the HTML/EPUB, there are the typical `P`,`H1`,`H2`,...`H6` tags, but in the PDF, there is an additional `H` option with no number attached. Is this a valid heading tag for PDFs? If it's not an option, I think the best I can do at the moment is categorize at least H1 text to be H1 tags, and any other heading text as H2 so that it's a flat hierarchy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic

Comment: Sorry, is there a better Stack Exchange community for this topic @VitalyMijiritsky? This was the closest community I could find for Accessibility, albeit a different kind of user experience

Comment: Accessibility is on-topic, but you're asking about specific implementation, while this site is dedicated to design & research, not implementation. You might want to check out either tex.SE or graphicdesign.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's valid but it's use is discouraged because it doesn't have a level, but it sounds like you're only doing this temporarily so maybe you'll be ok as long as you put a level back on it at some point.

If you edit the PDF in Acrobat and add a new tag or modify an existing tag, you'll see the plain "Heading" as an option before the Headings 1-6.

[image]

If you look at [ISO 32000-2:2020 (PDF 2.0)](https://www.iso.org/standard/75839.html), page 774 talks about the *Hn* element and page 775 talks about the *H* element.  It's not quite clear (to me) when the *H* tag is valid but here's what it says:

> Encloses a low-level division of content usually referred to as a heading. The heading level is not indicated through this structure element, but instead is derived from the nesting of the logical structure within a given Document or DocumentFragment structure element. The H heading structure elements should always be the first structure element within its parent structure element. The H heading structure element shall always be the only heading structure element within its parent structure element.
>
> NOTE 1 This implies that within a given logical document it is not acceptable that an H heading structure element is used if a H1, H2, H3 etc. heading structure element is also used inside the same DocumentFragment structure element.
>
> NOTE 2 The Lbl structure element can be used to enclose a section number or similar present inside the heading.
>
> EXAMPLE 1 As the use of the H heading structure element requires strict document structuring it is typically used only for machine generated documents, documents created from a well structured content data set or documents whose creation is fully controlled by a program such that its structure is strictly guaranteed.
>
> EXAMPLE 2 Scientific publications and technical specifications often follow very strict structuring rules and thus are suitable candidates for use of the H heading structure element.